# Cannot decode or read website URL for counting a string

Tags: python, regex, debugging, python-2.7, count

I am trying to perform a search and count of data in a website using the code below, you can see I have added a few extra prints in the code for debugging, currently the result is always "0" which says to me there is an error in reading the file of some sort. If I print the variable called html, I can clearly see that all three strings I am searching for are contained in the html, yet as previously mentioned none of my prints print anything, and the final print count simply returns "0". As you can see I have tried three different methods, same problem each time.

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import re
import json
import mechanize

post_url = "url_of_fishermans_finds"
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

html = browser.open(post_url).read().decode('UTF-8')

# Attempted method 1
print html.count("SEA BASS")

# Attempted method 2
count = 0
enabled = False
for line in html:
  if 'MAIN FISHERMAN' in line:
    print "found main fisherman"
    enabled = True
  elif 'SEA BASS' in line:
    print "found fish"
    count += 1
  elif 'SECONDARY FISHERMAN' in line:
    print "found secondary fisherman"
    enabled = False
print count

# Attempted method 3
relevant = re.search(r"MAIN FISHERMAN(.*)SECONDARY FISHERMAN", html)[1]
found = relevant.count("SEA BASS")
print found
```

It is probably something really simple, any comments or help would  be greatly appreciated. Kind regards AEA

Comment: You took into account that these search methods are case-sensitive so e.g. "sea bass" wouldn't be found?

Comment: Do a `line = line.upper()` after `for line in html:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your regular expressions method #3, it appears you aren't grouping your search result prior to running count.  I don't have the HTML you're looking at but you may also be running into trouble with your use of the '.' if there are newlines between your two search terms.  With these issues in mind, try something like the following to correct these errors (note: in Python 3 syntax):

```
relevantcompile = re.compile("MAIN FISHERMAN(.*)SECONDARY FISHERMAN", re.DOTALL)
relevantsearch = re.search(relevantcompile, html)
relevantgrouped = relevantsearch.group()
relevantcount = relevantgrouped.count("SEA BASS")
print(relevantcount)
```

Also, keep in mind comments above regarding the case sensitivity of regular expressions searches.  Hope this helps :)